# Post Multiple items / an array with Express & Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

unfortunately I have problems to post an Array to my Express Server.
I post an item and if it exists in the db it will be deleted.

My code:

item.routes.js

```
module.exports = app => {
    
  const item = require("../controllers/item.controller.js");

  app.post("/itemr", item.IsReserved);
};
```

item.controller.js

```
const Item = require("../models/item.model.js");

exports.IsReserved = (req, res) => {
  // Validate request
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Content can not be empty!"
    });
  }

  const item = new Item({
    itemId: req.body.assetId,
    botId: req.body.botId,
  });

  Item.IsReserved(item, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Item(db)."
      });
    else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

item.model.js

```
const sql = require("./db.js");

Item.IsReserved = (RItem, result) => {
    sql.query(`SELECT * FROM ReservedItems WHERE itemId = "${RItem.itemId}"`, (err, res) => {
        if(res.length){
            sql.query(`DELETE FROM ReservedItems WHERE itemId = "${RItem.itemId}"`, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error: ", err);
                    result(err, null);
                    return;
                }
                result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...RItem });
            });
        }
        else{
            result(null, { message: "nothing to do"});
        }
    });
};


module.exports = Item;
```

A single item works great with a post like this:

```
{
   "assetId" : 3,
   "botId" : "1"
}
```

but if I want to insert multiple items like this:

```
[
    {
        "assetId" : 3,
        "botId" : "1"
        },
        {
        "assetId" : 4,
        "botId" : "1"
    }
]
```

The result from this is "nothing to do"...

My sql log shows: `Query    SELECT * FROM ReservedItems WHERE itemId = "undefined"`

I saw another post here which had a similar problem, but I don't know how to implement something like ".create()" into my code to recognize multiple items.

I would be very thankful for every answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js request POST array "first argument must be string or buffer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290552/node-js-request-post-array-first-argument-must-be-string-or-buffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to fix your problem :)

First of all in your controller, this is not possible anymore as you send an array of items in your request payload. So you need to define an array aswell :

```
  const items = req.body.map((item) => new Item({
    itemId: item.assetId,
    botId: item.botId,
  });
```

As your method *IsReserved* handles only 1 item, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to apply modifications. Something like this :

```
Promise.all( items.map( (item) => Item.isReserved(item)))
.then( (result) => ...do something here)
.catch( (error) => ...do something else here)
```

Another approach could be to change the SQL statement and use *WHERE IN*

```
SELECT * FROM ReservedItems WHERE itemId IN (itemid1, itemid2...)
```

This will get you an array of items that you can then delete the same way. It seems better in terms of performance.

I also recommand to use async/await syntax as it's way easier to read code containing promises